# SwiftUI Stepper not working when bound to a model property directly

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-form

I am fairly new to iOS development. I am trying to update the property "cars" in the "Sire" model using a stepper. Whenever I press on + or - from the stepper controls, it changes the value by a step and then becomes disabled.

If I bind the stepper to the variable cars, it works flawlessly.

```
struct AddSireView: View {
//    @EnvironmentObject var sireVM:SiresViewModel
    @State var newSire = Sire (id:"", name: "", ownerID: 0, info:"", achievments: "", cars: 0, cups: 0)
    @State var cars = 0
    @State var cups = 0
    @State private var state = FormState.idle
    
    var createAction: CreateAction
    
    // TODO: Put validation that the added sire is valid and if not show errors to the user

    var body: some View {

            Form {
                VStack (spacing: 18) {
                    TitledTextView(text: $newSire.name, placeHolder: "الاسم", title: "الاسم")
                    
                    TiltedTextEditor(text: Binding<String>($newSire.info)!, title: "معلومات البعير")
                    TiltedTextEditor(text: Binding<String>($newSire.achievments)!, title: "انجازات البعير")
                }
                
                Stepper(value: $newSire.cars, in: 0...10,step:1) {
                    HStack {
                        Text ("سيارات:")
                        TextField("Cars", value: $newSire.cars, formatter: NumberFormatter.decimal)
                    }
                }
```

[image]

And this is the "Sire" struct

```
struct Sire: Hashable, Identifiable, Decodable  {
    static func == (lhs: Sire, rhs: Sire) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id && lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.ownerID == rhs.ownerID
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
        hasher.combine(name)
        hasher.combine(ownerID)

    }
     var id:String
     var name:String
     var ownerID:Int
     var fatherID:String?
     var info:String?
     var achievments:String?
     var cars:Int = 0
     var cups:Int = 0
    
     
    init (id:String, name:String, ownerID:Int, info:String? = nil, achievments:String? = nil,
          fatherID:String? = nil, cars:Int = 0, cups:Int = 0) {
         self.id = id
         self.name = name
         self.ownerID = ownerID
         self.cars = cars
         self.cups = cups
        self.info = info
        self.achievments = achievments
     }  
     
}
```

"Sire" was a class and i made it a Struct thinking that that was the problem, but to no avail.

Comment: Get rid of the custom implementations for Equatable and Washable you don't include `cars` in it so SwiftUI doesn't know when to reload.

Comment: @loremipsum This solved the problem. Now it is working. Thanks so much.Could you refer to me to relevant documentation or explain it to me? Could you put it as an answer to check it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the custom implementations for `Equatable` and `Hashable` (`func ==` and `func hash`) you don't include `cars` in it so SwiftUI doesn't know when to reload.

SwiftUI is all about identity if you change how Swift computes the identity (using `Hashable`, `Equatable` and `Identifiable`) you change the behavior.

[Check out Demystify SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10022)

The video above is the "best" place to learn about the concept.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this approach using an `ObservableObject` to hold your `Sire`. This allows you to use
both the `Stepper` and the `Textfield` at the same time.

```
 struct ContentView: View {
     @StateObject var sireModel = SireModel() // <-- here
     
     var body: some View {
         Form {
             Stepper(value: $sireModel.sire.cars, in: 0...10, step:1) {
                 HStack {
                     Text ("سيارات: ")
                     TextField("", value: $sireModel.sire.cars, formatter: NumberFormatter())
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }

 class SireModel: ObservableObject {
     @Published var sire: Sire = Sire(id:"", name: "", ownerID: 0, info:"", achievments: "", cars: 0, cups: 0)
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't address the cause of the issue it is just a workaround.